# Uncompressing NSData

Tags: iphone, compression

I am zipping a folder and uploading the zip file to the server. I am then downloading to to my game. It's being received into NSMutableData. Now how can I unzip it and use it in the game?

I am able to download pngs, plists and pvr.ccz and use it in the game. What I am trying to do is be able to download additional content for the game from the server. I am looking for a way where I can zip up the all the extra resources and store it on the server and then download it when I need and unzip to use it.

Do let me know if you can help me out with this.

Thanks
AC

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ZipKit](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/overview) to make the process of unzipping files very easy.  As far as I understand (though untested, and should have error checking), you would do something like this:

```
ZKDataArchive *archive = [ZKDataArchive archiveWithArchiveData:data];  // 'data' must be NSMutableData, not just NSData
[archive inflateInFolder:folderPath withFolderName:someFolderName usingResourceFork:NO];
```

I think you would unzip this to the Documents folder and then load these into your game using their absolute paths.

Comment: This is great. Thanks. I am having trouble integrating ZipKit though. Hopefully it works out. Thanks a bunch.  Also if you know of any alternate kits to ZipKit that would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because I wanted to zip up a bunch load of files, including TexturePacker files, together and then have them downloaded onto the game. So I ended up using this wrapper called ZipArchive & SSZipArchive. It is using minizip. I zip my files and upload them. Then download them using NSURLConnection

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

and save them under the documents directory and unzip that using

```
-(BOOL) UnzipFileTo:(NSString*) path overWrite:(BOOL) overwrite
```

Pretty simple now that it's figured out :)